# Domain of first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My textbook contains following definition about domain of differential equation: If $$y'=f(x,y) \tag{1}$$ is a differential equation in normal form, we consider also reciprocal equation $$x'=\frac{1}{f(x,y)}=g(x,y) \tag{2}$$We say that domain of differential equation $(1)$ is union of domains of $f$ and $g$ minus points $(x,y)$ for which both $f$ and $g$ are not simultaneously zero. Now, we can combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ in form $$dy-f(x,y)dx$$ and if we multiply it by some function $N(x,y)$ we get equation in differential form $$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0 \tag{3}$$It is said that domain of differential equation in differential form is union of all points from common domain of $M$ and $N$ for which it is true that $$M^2(x,y)+N^2(x,y)\not=0 \tag{4}$$Obviously we can get normal form from differential form by solving for $y'$ i.e. $$y'=-\frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$$But why it is then not enough to say that domain of differential equation in differential form is all points in common domain of $M$ and $N$ for which they are not simultaneously equal to zero. Why use $(4)$? What is the point of squares in $(4)$? Any explanation is appreciated. Thanks in advance.